# Django-tables2 specifying verbose_name for column header has no effect

Tags: django, django-tables2

This seems like a very simple issue with no apparent cause.

I'm trying to set a verbose name in a Django Tables2 table to change the column header. The [documentation](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/column-headers-and-footers.html) indicates this is the correct way to do this.

My table is simple, like so:

```
class ContestantsTable(tables.Table):
    
    id = tables.Column(verbose_name='Contestant ID')
    full_name = tables.Column(verbose_name='Name')
    
    class Meta:
        model = Contestant
        template_name = "django_tables2/bootstrap.html"
        fields = ("id", "full_name")
```

The verbose name setting is completely ignored. If I set `verbose_name` on the field in the model it works, but I want to do this at the table level and not on the model (The name I want for the column won't be used elsewhere).

I have another table where I am trying to set `default="Unassigned` which also does not reflect in the table for fields where there is no entry.

I'm not sure why such a simple thing is failing.

edit: Adding in my view and template

My view is:

```
class viewcontestants(LoginRequiredMixin, SingleTableView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = Contestant.objects.filter(approved=True).order_by('-id')
        return qs
    
    def get_template_names(self):
        return 'mysite/contestants.html'

    def get_table_class(self):
        return ContestantsTable
```

and my template:

```
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <body>
    {% render_table table %}       
    </body>
</html>
```

edit2: If I override the init method and sspecify verbose name on the field it works, but not by passing it as a paramter per the documentation

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ContestantsTable, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.base_columns['full_name'].verbose_name = 'Name'
```

Comment: On my site it works correctly. Can you share some more code where the form is used in the view and template?

Comment: @Marco sure. In template is just the line to render template, and the view is a very simple cbv, not sure why this isn't working.

Comment: I checked with your code and it works. Not sure where we miss something.

Comment: @Marco yeah it seems strange, I made sure to restart my web server several times, make no difference. At least changing by overriding init works, it might be useful to someone else having the same issue.